# Python float types vs Decimal

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, decimal

I am an intern at TCD, Physics.

I wrote a code to perform some data analysis on random particle packings. The code is written in Python.

The code reads in columns of data from a .txt file, provided by my supervisor.

Here is an example of the data:

```
0.52425196504624715921  0.89754790324432953685  0.44222783508101531913
```

I wrote the following code to read in the data:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from numpy import *

c1,c2,r = loadtxt("second.txt", usecols=(0,1,2), unpack=True, dtype = dtype(Decimal))
```

As you can see I used the Decimal dtype to read in all the decimal places of the number, and to be sure the calculations were reliable.

Now, in order to speed up my code, I was wondering if there was a numpy dtype to make things faster, still using all decimal places, though. I did try:

```
c1,c2,r = loadtxt("second.txt", usecols=(1,2,4), unpack=True, dtype = float128)
```

and

```
c1,c2,r = loadtxt("second.txt", usecols=(1,2,4), unpack=True, dtype = longdouble)
```

However here is the output compared:

```
Decimal :    0.98924652608783791852
float128 :   0.98924653
longdouble : 0.98924653
float32 :    0.98924655
```

I am using a desktop, 64bit, 4GB RAM.

Well, then I tried writing a code in C++ that basically multiplies every element of the columns of data by enough powers of 10 such that a new .txt file was produced with the following columns:

```
52425196504624715921    89754790324432953685    44222783508101531913
```

But when back to my Python code (I have to do this in Python):

```
  c1,c2,r = loadtxt("second.txt", usecols=(1,2,4), unpack=True, dtype = int)
```

I get the following error message:

```
 OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Please pardon my limited knowledge of the language.

Any solution is extremely welcome: I really need to speed up the code, either by reading directly the data or performing the required conversion to integers.

Comment: Are you sure that the differences between your results for the `Decimal` and `np.floatX` types aren't just because of differences in the display precision for the different types? Try doing a `print ".20%f" %floatXresult`, or testing whether `decimalresult == floatXresult`.

Comment: I'd load everything and do the computations using `dtype=np.float64` unless you have strong reasons to need more precision (like having to use algorithms very sensitive to rounding errors). Ie, don't worry about it. By the way, "never" import any module as `from X import *` (it pollutes the namespace, makes it hard to use tools to analyze code, numpy will overwrite builtin functions... The standard way to import numpy is `import numpy as np`).

Comment: instead of using `dtype = int` use `dtype=long`. the numbers you have are too big for an int